# VRT File with zipped files no longer working in QGIS 3.32.2

Tags: qgis, gdalbuildvrt

I created a .vrt of a number of a number of .tif files, each in a separate zip file, using gdalbuilvrt with the following command (in powershell for those wondering about the "&" at the front):

```
& "C:\OSGeo4W\bin\gdalbuildvrt.exe" -input_file_list "FileList.txt" "LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022.vrt"
```

Filelist.txt looks something like this:

```
/vsizip/Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ34ne.zip\TQ34ne_FZ_DSM_1m.tif
/vsizip/Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ34nw.zip\TQ34nw_FZ_DSM_1m.tif
/vsizip/Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ35ne.zip\TQ35ne_FZ_DSM_1m.tif
/vsizip/Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ35nw.zip\TQ35nw_FZ_DSM_1m.tif
/vsizip/Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ35se.zip\TQ35se_FZ_DSM_1m.tif
/vsizip/Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ35sw.zip\TQ35sw_FZ_DSM_1m.tif
/vsizip/Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ44nw.zip\TQ44nw_FZ_DSM_1m.tif
/vsizip/Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ45nw.zip\TQ45nw_FZ_DSM_1m.tif
/vsizip/Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ45sw.zip\TQ45sw_FZ_DSM_1m.tif
```

The resulting .vrt worked fine in QGIS 3.22 but no longer works in QGIS 3.32 - I get the following error:

> LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022: `/vsizip/Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ34ne.zip\TQ34ne_FZ_DSM_1m.tif' does not
> exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset
> name.

I thought there might have been an update to either the .vrt support so I tried recreating the vrt using the latest gdalbuildvrt, using the same code and files above. This now throws an error for each file:

> Warning 1: Can't open /vsizip/Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ34ne.zip\TQ34ne_FZ_DSM_1m.tif. Skipping it

We have recently migrated to a new server (and so Z is now mapped to the new file system containing those files).

Is this due to the server migration, a bug that's crept in or do I need to change the way in which I create the .vrt?

Comment: I had some troubles with /vsizip/ as well and got the hint from @EvenRouault to use an alternative syntax with curved brackets `/vsizip/{/path/to/the/archive}/path/inside/the/zip/file`: https://github.com/sozip/sozip-spec/issues/7. You could even try to use the UNC path instead of your Z: drive letter.

Comment: Or maybe you need some double quotes because of the space inside the ZIP file path.

Comment: @christoph Thanks for the tip. Having played a bit, there is obviously an issue with the path - stripping out "Z:\Environment Agency\" from the paths allows the command to run. However, the resulting .vrt when loaded still gives the first error as above.

Comment: Does `/vsizip/{Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ34ne.zip}\TQ34ne_FZ_DSM_1m.tif` work?

Comment: The command runs but the .vrt errors in QGIS as per the first quote.

Comment: Maybe you need double quotes? `/vsizip/{"Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ34ne.zip"}\TQ34ne_FZ_DSM_1m.tif`

Comment: Tried that. `/vsizip/{LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ45sw.zip}/TQ45sw_FZ_DSM_1m.tif` works for the command as does `/vsizip/LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ45sw.zip/TQ45sw_FZ_DSM_1m.tif`. So I can now get gdalbuildvrt to find the tifs using vsizip whilst creating the .vrt but then loading the .vrt doesn't work in qgis.

Comment: If you are saving the VRT near the data, you don't need the full path.  Say your VRT is "Z:\Environment Agency\LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022.vrt", if you open your command prompt in (or `cd` to) Z:\Environment Agency, then run `gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list "FileList.txt" "LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022.vrt"` where FileList.txt contains just the *.zip\*.tif without the full path, e.g. `LIDAR-FZ_DSM-1m-2022-TQ34ne.zip\TQ34ne_FZ_DSM_1m.tif` etc...

Comment: @user2856 - that's just what I did in the previous comment. `/vsizip/` is still required, gdalbuildvrt can't open a .zip without it. As I said, I can now get gdalbuildvrt to run without error on the file list, but the resulting .vrt still doesn't work in QGIS

Comment: I didn't say without the /vsizip/ I said without the Z:\Environment Agency so you would have a relative path. But doesn't matter, relative paths won't work with /vsizip/ https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2012-March/031987.html